# So much for a type safety with generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

There is something strange I can't wrap my head about. Generics is a good thing in general. It gives a type-safety at compile time. For example:

```
class A{}

class B{}

static void someMethod() {
    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
    listB.add(B);
    listB.add(A); // here goes a compiler error

    // but this will compile fine
    List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    objList.add("String");
    objList.add(new Integer(9));
    objList.add(B);
}
```

Well, is it something Java developers missed?

Comment: What are you asking after -- whether generics offer type safety?

Comment: Make `class A extends B{}` and retry.

Comment: Nope, you missed something. ;)

Comment: Your example actually proves type safety

Comment: You might also want to look up what a "subtype relation" is.

Comment: To avoid downvotes in the future, try not to point the accusing finger to Java immediately, but to yourself first :)

Comment: It is worth remembering that Java is used by millions of people and been test/developed over 15 years.  It has it problems, but you would need at least 10 years experience to say with confidence what they are.

Comment: Don't bear a grudge, I didn't mean to offend anyone. Actually I like Java more and more as I go along. Betting quite a lot on it, indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a list of `Objects`, you're **allowed to add Objects**. That's why you can add instances of `String`, `Integer` and `B`... **they are all objects!**

Perhaps you wonder why one is not **only** allowed to add `Objects`. Well, it can be quite handy to allow for subtypes to be added. Consider for instance that you want to store lots of numbers in a list. You don't know if they are floating point numbers or integers etc. Then you could do

```
List<Number> numList = new ArrayList<Number>();
numList.add(new Double(5.5));
numList.add(new Integer(5));
numList.add(new Long(10L));
```

Answer (score 12):

Object is the base class of everything and you are adding objects of type Object. Therefore type safe (as all inserted objects fulfill the requirement of being of type object).

Answer (score 3):

In simple words, `"String"` `new Integer(9)` and `B` are `Object`, whereas `B` is not `A`.

In inheritance, if 
`A` extends `B`,  then `A is said to be of type`A`and`B`as well;`
Object`is the`super` class of all the class.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
```

is interpreted as

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

so, in fact, adding arbitrary Objects to this list is fine. This should emit a warning when it is compiled because you are using a parameterised type with no parameters.

It was implemented this way to preserve backward compatibility. If all non-parameterised code that used `new ArrayList()` (or any other collections framework class) suddenly didn't compile then that would cost an enormous amount of time and money to fix. Yes, it means you can write unsafe code, but you get warned about it and at least your existing 10-million-line application still works.

Answer (score 0):

Java generics do provide proper type safety, but you are not specifying the boundaries appropriately.  Here is an example what generics actually provide you with:

```
List<Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>();
list1.add(new Integer(1)); // can add anything that is a Number
list1.add(new Double(1.0));
Number n = list1.get(0); // and retrieve Numbers

List<? super Number> list2 =  new ArrayList<Number>(); // can be a list of number
list2 = new ArrayList<Object>(); // or a list of objects
list2.add(new Integer(1)); // but can only add numbers
list2.add(new Double(1.0));
Object o1 = list2.get(0); // and only retrieve Objects

List<? extends Number> list3 = new ArrayList<Number>(); // can be a list of numbers
list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // or any subtype of Number
list3 = new ArrayList<Double>();
list3.add(null); // but can add any thing to it
Number n2 = list3.get(0); // and only retrieve Numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason your first example fails is because `A is not a`B`.

the reason the second example works is because `String`, `new Integer(9)`, and `B` are all `Object`s.

This makes good logical sense, and practical for the reasons other posters said.